# I need help for Ansile automation for weblogic 11g on AWS Ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, server, automation, weblogic11g

How to Create automation script using Ansible to install weblogic 11g and its components like managed servers, clusters, node manager, machines on the AWS EC2 (Linux OS) host server

Answer (score 0):

You can check this repository in GitHub to get some ideas.

https://github.com/textanalyticsman/ansible-soa

These playbooks install Weblogic 12.2.1.4 , SOA 12.2.1.4, run RCU and configure a domain composed by an AdminServer and two managed servers each one living in its own machine. Adapting these scripts for Weblogic 11g should not be difficult.